# Scroll window without a jump (javascript or hashtag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hashtag

I want a solution either using a hashtag pointing at the name of an anchor tag or javascript.

The javascript I am currently using looks like this `window.scroll(0, 20000);`. The problem is that this causes the window jerk down when a user arrives on the page.

I know there are jQuery animations that make this movement more gradual. However, what I want is something that makes the movement of the window imperceptible to the user. I want to be as if the user landed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This is challenging to execute.  The size of your page, the amount of JavaScript you have processing, and the possibility of dynamically loaded content all factor into initial page load and behavior.  My gut says you should try just using anchors with IDs and hashtags in your URLs, the ol' fashion way, but it sounds like you've already tried that.

Comment: Hashtags are a twitter tagging system. Those are [fragment identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem  you face is that you wish to go to the bottom of your page which has not loaded yet. I would consider loading the page in a hidden format then show it when it has all loaded and after scrolling the user at the location you want. Use the focus or scroll to methods.

Take a look at the filament group website.

http://filamentgroup.com/

they hide the page with a loading screen until it is ready.

This way there is no jerk.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I try and do it this way the new content pushing down the old content and the scroll isn't held. If there is any way that I could anchor it at the bottom of the page this would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

In loop it works, if the page is fully loaded and shown:

```
for(var n=0;n<1000;n++) window.scrollBy(0,20);
```

(Notice that 20*1000=20000, which was the original place to scroll.)

Comment: When you say it works, what do you mean? This code still gives me the same jerky motion.

Comment: "It" means the scrolling-statement, sorry for my bad english. Are you sure your page is fully loaded before calling this statement? And also completely shown in browser? If your page is very large, browser does work long after it has fired the onload-event.

Answer (score 0):

Teemu's answer doesn't seem to work for me (it goes straight to the bottom, making the loop with scrollBy stepping invisible), because it doesn't implement a delay.

If you mean to animate from top to bottom of the page in a 1000ms, try something more like this:

```
for (var n = 0; n < 1000; n += 1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollBy(0, document.height / 1000);
    }, n);
}
```

That will give a 1 second (1000ms) animation, scrolling to the bottom in roughly 1000 steps.